# Добавление выбранных значений в селектор, в вал

Tags: jquery

По клику добавляю элементам класс `active-job`, необходимо у всех элементов, имеющих данный класс, получить текстовое значение, записать в `value` и вывести в селекторе с классом `.list-job__res`:

```
 <div class="list-job__select">
   <span class="list-job__res"></span>
   <input type="text" class="list-job__res-val" name="list_vacancy" required="">
  <div class="list-job" style="display: block;">
    <div class="list-job__item">1</div>
    <div class="list-job__item">2</div>
  </div>
</div>

$(".list-job__item").on("click",function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active-job");
  active = $(this).find(".active-job");
  $.each(active, function( index ) {
     console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
     txt = array.push($( this ).text())
  });

  $(this).closest(".list-job__select").find(".list-job__res").text(txt);

  $(this).closest(".list-job__select").find(".list-job__res-val").val(txt)
})
```

Comment: в чем состоит вопрос? и  что, по-вашему, вы делаете тут `txt = array.push($( this ).text())` ?

Comment: `array.push` возвращает _новую длину_ массива, после добавления, а не значение, которое ты добавлял

Comment: по сути нужно получить текста всех выбранных элементов(у кого стоит класс active-job) записать это всё в переменную

Answer (score 1):

1. метод [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) собирает текст *всех* элементов в выборке, поэтому по сути цикл не нужен
2. метод [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) ищет элементы *внутри* элементов в текущей выборке, а так как текущая выборка у тебя `$(this)`, где `this` - это элемент с классом *list-job__item*, в котором нет других элементов, то твой запрос вернет пустую коллекцию, вместо этого можно подняться до родителя, и искать внутри родителя.

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```js
$(".list-job__item").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active-job");
  var select = $(this).closest(".list-job__select")
  var activeText = select.find('.active-job').text();;

  select.find(".list-job__res").text(activeText);

  select.find(".list-job__res-val").val(activeText)
})
```

```css
.list-job__item {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .25rem .15rem;
}

.list-job__res-val {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>


<div class="list-job__select">
  <span class="list-job__res"></span>
  <input type="text" class="list-job__res-val" name="list_vacancy" required="">
  <div class="list-job" style="display: block;">
    <div class="list-job__item">1</div>
    <div class="list-job__item">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

например:

```js
$(".list-job__item").on("click", function(){
  var
    $this = $(this),
      wrap = $this.closest('.list-job__select'),
      input = wrap.find('.list-job__res-val'),
      res = wrap.find('.list-job__res');
  
  if(!$this.hasClass('active-job') ){
    $this.addClass('active-job')
         .siblings()
         .removeClass('active-job');
    input.val($this.text());
    res.html($this.text());
  }else {
    $this.removeClass('active-job');
    input.val(' ');
    res.html(' ');
  }    

});
```

```css
.list-job__item {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .25rem .15rem;
}

.list-job__res-val {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

  
<div class="list-job__select">
  <span class="list-job__res"></span>
  <input type="text" class="list-job__res-val" name="list_vacancy" required="">
  <div class="list-job" style="display: block;">
    <div class="list-job__item">1</div>
    <div class="list-job__item">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у автора вопроса может быть несколько активных элементов, а у тебя только один